# gazebosim.org down?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is gazebo website not working???

prince

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134256/gazebosim.org-down?/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2014-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, here in the Netherlands it works.
From here it is the same: http://isup.me/gazebosim.org

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2014-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0